Multiple stories, one character is named "Pink"
What is the name of this movie?
It's an Asian movie, there are 3 stories, the first is a girl with a cast on her leg, she's browsing the internet and then she noticed a funeral outside. Second is friends going camping. The third is with a girl named Pink.
I think it's in Japanese, and it's done one at a time. In the first part, the girl received a text on her cellphone from an unknown man, and when she looked outside at the funeral she accidentally dropped something (a flower, I think). In the second part, the men who are camping near a lake are murdered one by one.

Can you be more specific than "Asian"? Do you know the country? What language was it in? Can you give any more detail about the plot? Are the stories connected at all? Are they interwoven or are they done one at a time?

i think its in japanese, and its done one at a time. at the first part, the girl received a text on her cellphone from an unknown man, and when she looked outside at the funeral she accidentally dropped something(a flower i think). at the second part, the men who are camping near a lake are murdered one by one. i cant remember much, sorry

You're looking for the 2008 Thai film Phobia (AKA 4bia AKA See Prang). From IMDb:

4BIA is a Horror Anthology. The first segment, "Happiness" is about a lonely girl [with a cast on her leg] who corresponded with a stranger over hand phone text messaging and soon discovered something strange about this new stranger that she is attracted to. "Tit For Tat" spun a tale of black magic and vengeance for a school kid that had been bullied by a school gang. "In The Middle" - a group of friends faced one of their worst camping trip after water kayaking accident. The final segment "Last Fright" takes horror to new heights with a psychological thriller that involves a stewardess flying solo in a cabin with a dead body. 

One of the girls in 'Tit For Tat' is called Pink. Here's the trailer:



